# How do I pull a single object from a nested array?

Tags: python, mongodb

I've got Mongo running in a Docker container.

In Mongo Bash I can pull the entire JSON file with db..find()

But I can't isolate a single object with the code below:

`db.FilmList.find({"Films" : {Title : "Clue"}})`    or any variation I can think of.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. Pretty new to the syntax but learning it.

Comment: Please do not rely on screenshots to show code and/or sample data. It makes the post far less readable than if you specific your test data in text and shows low effort.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
db.FilmList.find({"Films.Title" : "Clue"}, {"Films.$": 1, _id : 0})
```